# How to search in String Array in an Array of Docs

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can i find all docs in an array which have a certain value in an array like hobby's. How can i find for example all user which have ski as a hobby and is it also possible to find all who have golf and soccer in one statement or will i have to reduce array by first find all soccer and then find all who also pay golf ?
The basic filter does not work and most samples i found only cover the case where the array has a key / value pair.
Tried the below with no luck

const filteredData = data.filter(x => x.hobby(e => e ==='ski')

```
[{ "user" : 1,
  "name" : "demo 1",
  "hobby" : ["soccer", "golf", "ski"],
  "age" : 24
},
{ "user" : 2,
  "name" : "demo 2",
  "hobby" : ["soccer", "ski"],
  "age" : 27
},
{ "user" : 3,
  "name" : "demo 3",
  "hobby" : [ "ski"],
  "age" : 21
},{ "user" : 4,
  "name" : "demo 4",
  "hobby" : ["soccer", "golf"],
  "age" : 24
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter` and `includes` like that

```js
const data = [{
    "user": 1,
    "name": "demo 1",
    "hobby": ["soccer", "golf", "ski"],
    "age": 24
  },
  {
    "user": 2,
    "name": "demo 2",
    "hobby": ["soccer", "ski"],
    "age": 27
  },
  {
    "user": 3,
    "name": "demo 3",
    "hobby": ["ski"],
    "age": 21
  }, {
    "user": 4,
    "name": "demo 4",
    "hobby": ["soccer", "golf"],
    "age": 24
  }
];

const resSki = data.filter(({
  hobby
}) => hobby.includes("ski"))

console.log(resSki)

const resSoccerGolf = data.filter(({
  hobby
}) => hobby.includes("soccer") && hobby.includes("golf"));

console.log(resSoccerGolf)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use for loops and a switch, if you search for more than one thing you don't have to loop trough the array more than once.

```
const arr = [
  { user: 1, name: 'demo 1', hobby: ['soccer', 'golf', 'ski'], age: 24 },
  { user: 2, name: 'demo 2', hobby: ['soccer', 'ski'], age: 27 },
  { user: 3, name: 'demo 3', hobby: ['ski'], age: 21 },
  { user: 4, name: 'demo 4', hobby: ['soccer', 'golf'], age: 24 }
];
for (const item of arr) {
  for (const hobby of item.hobby) {
    switch (hobby) {
      case 'ski':
        console.log(`${item.name} likes to ski`);
        break;
      case 'soccer':
        console.log(`${item.name} likes to play soccer`);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```